# After updating firefox 55 Inline images (img) is not rendering in HTML CANVAS through SVG

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, svg, html5-canvas

I have developed a **CANVAS** area in which few HTML elements are rendering as **SVG data**. It was working perfect before **firefox** new updated version. Now, after this recent update only CSS background images are rendering. Inline images through img tag is showing nothing.

I can't use css background images because, of some limitations. I have to show colors in background and some PNG images on upper layer through higher z-index and position:absolute properties. So, that it will feel like color drawing in transparent area.

**Updated** - Sample code -

```
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
         "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
           "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px;background-color:#0f0'>" +
             "<em>I</em> like <span style='color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;'>cheese</span>" +
           "<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' width='150' height='150'/></div>" +
         "</foreignObject>" +
       "</svg>";
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200,200);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
img.src = url;
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: I think [I've got one](https://jsfiddle.net/7qzrv71r/), very strange indeed... `SVGImage` will render, but `<img>` in `<foreignObject>` won't when the svg doc is itself rendered in an HTMLImage element, but will when in an iframe... One answer is [*file a bug*](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi#h=product%7C) (It actually has nothing to do with canvas)

Comment: I just filled a bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1409992 Let's see what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is confirmed to be a bug in Firefox versions >= 55 < 58.
 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1409992

It is now fixed in current Nightly build 58.

No known workaround unfortunatetly..